# Where and what is my unit test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have been reading tons of articles on unit testing. I am specifically using angular.js right now and came to the conclusion that unit testing = great. I also understand what unit tests are conceptually, but I honestly have no idea what I am doing or looking for. I already started the angular application and before I continue, I feel like I should start testing units of it. I have started tutorials and everything tells me "how" to do it using jasmine (or the other ones).  I have a node project set up that is running Karma and a folder that has some *.js files in it to do all the describing/testing. However, it feels like the "tests" I write in a js sit in that file and do nothing.

What am I looking for? How do I actually view the results of the tests? It is all there, but I have no idea where exactly I am supposed to start. Am I supposed to be able to view the test in the browser? Is it supposed to run and save to a log file? Is it actually supposed to be tied to my ACTUAL code, or is it just rewritten logic that is supposed to mimic my code for testing?

This may be a dumb question, but I have spent a long time trying to figure out what exactly to look for. I noticed in some tutorials people have had little  windows that tell them if their tests are failing or not (webstorm I believe) while they are writing the tests.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) for an example of a test project.  Maybe you're looking for a CI (continuous integration) solution?

Comment: I just wrote a bit of an answer like this to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518571/how-to-mock-an-object-within-an-angularjs-factory-method/24518664#24518664 - As far as running / viewing tests look a Grunt

Comment: This is also a very similar question with a few good answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437148/unit-testing-in-angular/24437284

Comment: maybe this as well http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html

Comment: Thanks for all the tips/help guys. I think I started piecing it together. I looked at the all the links, and I actually had already used the yearofmoo tutorial. However, after going through and rereading it slower, playing with the angular-seed, I think I am catching on.

I realized also that I am running tests via js files and they are being automatically run in my cmd/terminal. The files for my app are also included in the karma config file. A lot of the tutorials kept talking about browsers and headless browsers and I didn't think to look at cmd prompts. Thanks! I have a lot to learn!